# Asure deployed app, Hostinger hosted, website accessibility issue different geographies/locations

Tags: azure, web-applications, subdomain, hosting, azure-webapps

The domain of my company is hosted on Hostinger (domain hosting service). I have created a subdomain also.
I have deployed a web application on Azure cloud and used the subdomain to point to Azure VM instance IP address. The A record is updated and reflected correctly by DNS checker everywhere across the world.

I'm facing a peculiar problem. When I access the website in office it is accessible, when my colleague working remotely wants to access she is seeing a Test page from Hostinger. Another colleague in a different city is able to access the application at the created subdomain. An international colleague is also unable to see it.

At a particular location if I use a VPN and set my location to a different geography the website becomes accessible.

I'm unable to understand this behavior and reason for this issue. Have I missed something during setup? I never faced this issue on AWS hosted applications.

Thanks all for the help.
[image: Access by VPN]

[image: No access Test page]

Comment: Sounds like you deployed your app on VM and not an app service. I would use tracert, https://dnspropagation.net/ and https://www.digwebinterface.com/ from those client machines to see what the subdomain is resolving to. Definitely sounds like a routing issue. Are those clients able to access the site using the public IP?

Comment: @RyanHill, The DNS propagation always returns positive results. I exchanged with Hostinger and they said to speak to Microsoft. I could not exchange with Microsoft staff. I checked today over VPN for different locations. The issue seems to have resolved. I asked a friend in France to check and the same test page. When you say it is a routing issue, how do you suggest I debug and resolve this? I don't even know where to start as DNS checker always shows mapping is propagated.

Comment: You want to see how the traffic is being routed from the client machine. So your friend and France should run tracert to the URI endpoint of your site to see how it's getting routed. You should also want that client to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/howto-troubleshoot-network-trace to observe how that particular client is getting to a test page whereas everyone else gets to your site correctly.